# git-ftp resmo git-ftp.log

Tags: git, upload, ftp, git-ftp

I'm using git-ftp by resmo. 
https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp.
When I run the first init command (and olso with push) like this

```
git ftp init -vv -u xxxxxxx@aruba.it -p - ftp.mydomain.com
```

There is a fatal problem

```
There are 1 files to sync:
[1 of 1] Buffered for upload 'index.php'.
Uploading ...
fatal: Could not upload file: '.git-ftp.log'., exiting...
fatal: Could not upload., exiting...
```

the full resonse here http://jsfiddle.net/ehijon/PHwpw/

for be sure I set config file in ".git" local folder with:

```
[git-ftp]
user = xxxxxxx@aruba.it
url = ftp://ftp.mydomain.com
password = xxmypassxx
deployedsha1file = public/.git-ftp.log
```

after I set "public" folder on remote with 777 permissions but in local I have not this file (.git-ftp.log)... what can I do to create it?

I tried to create it in remote manually, just for know if I have the permission and I can.

The ftp user and pass are correct. What can I do for solve this issue?

Comment: If the issue is solved, please move your edit from above into an answer to that the question is removed from the "unanswered" list ;)

Comment: ok, I made it, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of tests I found the stupid problem.
Aruba.it (an italian host) create a subdirectory in the root
like this:

```
~/www.mydomain.com/public/...
```

so just set the folder after the ftp in the url parameter:

```
url = ftp://ftp.mydomain.com/www.mydomain.com/public
```

...I hope this can help someone